# How can we join the results with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregation

Here i am joining three tables and want to get the result by group by method.when i wrote the query like this

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT p.id, p.customerid, T.u_id, A.u_id, T.agent_name,
       P.date as d_date, T.total_profit, A.t_price, A.t_dc
  FROM bills P
  LEFT JOIN((SELECT *,
                    bill_details.id as b_id,
                    bill_details.user_id as u_id,
                    SUM(bill_details.profit) AS total_profit
               FROM bill_details
              WHERE DATE(bill_details.bill_date) BETWEEN '{$start_date}' AND
                    '{$end_date}'
                AND bill_details.user_id = 406
              GROUP BY Date(bill_details.bill_date), bill_details.user_id) T)
    ON p.id = T.bill_id
  LEFT JOIN((SELECT *,
                    assigned_result.assigned_result_id as a_id,
                    assigned_result.user_id as u_id,
                    SUM(assigned_result.total_price) AS t_price,
                    SUM(assigned_result.total_dc) AS t_dc
               FROM assigned_result
              WHERE DATE(assigned_result.date) BETWEEN '{$start_date}' AND
                    '{$end_date}'
                AND assigned_result.user_id = 406
              GROUP BY Date(assigned_result.date), assigned_result.user_id) A)
    ON p.id = A.bill_no
 WHERE T.u_id = 406
    OR A.u_id = 406");
  return $query->result();
```

if am doing group_by condition like this `GROUP BY T.u_id,A.u_id`
My output looks like this

```
Name    Date          Purchase      Winning     Balance

        2019-07-25                    240        -240

Ned     2019-07-25     132.60        0.00         132
```

i want the result to be like this

```
Name    Date          Purchase      Winning     Balance

Ned     2019-07-25    132.60          240          132
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an extra `max()` aggregation:

```
SELECT max(Name) as Name, Date, max(Purchase) as Purchase, 
       max(Winning) as Winning, max(Balance) as Balance
  FROM
  (
   <YourOriginalQuery>
  ) q
 GROUP BY Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the query with your `GROUP BY`.  But from what you describe, you can do either:

- Remove the `GROUP BY` entirely.  The aggregation query will return one row.
- Use `GROUP BY COALESCE(T.u_id, A.u_id)

You may need to adjust the `SELECT` clause as well, if these columns are in the `SELECT`.